# Unserialize array and output data from within it

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, serialization

I am recieving the following from the database.

```
 Array
  (
 [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [userid] => 2
        [collection_name] => Programm Title
        [collection_data] => a:2:{i:2;a:7:{s:10:"ExerciseID";s:1:"2";s:11:"Description";s:11:"Description";s:4:"Sets";s:3:"123";s:4:"Reps";s:3:"123";s:4:"Load";s:3:"123";s:4:"Rest";s:3:"123";s:5:"Tempo";s:3:"123";}i:3;a:7:{s:10:"ExerciseID";s:1:"3";s:11:"Description";s:0:"";s:4:"Sets";s:0:"";s:4:"Reps";s:0:"";s:4:"Load";s:0:"";s:4:"Rest";s:0:"";s:5:"Tempo";s:0:"";}}
    )`

)
```

I wish to unserialize the `collection_data` which will give me an array like this:

```
Array
(
[434] => Array
    (
        [ExerciseID] => 434
        [Description] => 
        [Sets] => 
        [Reps] => 
        [Load] => 
        [Rest] => 
        [Tempo] => 
    )

)
```

I then wish to run the following to query the database for the exercise ID's.

```
  $ids = array();

  if(empty($newdata))
 {echo"<p>There is something wrong with that link, please speak to your coach!</p>";}
 else
 {
foreach($newdata as $el)
 {
  $ids[] = $el['ExerciseID'];
 }
 }
// START OF THE QUERY USING THE EXERCISE ID'S FOR DISPLAYING IN THE COLLECTION
$the_query = new WP_Query(array('post__in' => $ids, 'post_type' =>   'exercise','posts_per_page' =>'40')); ?>

 <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() && $ids ) : ?>

 <!-- the loop to get the psots that are in the array / collection -->
 <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

  <!--   <?php the_post_thumbnail('collection_thumb'); ?> -->
 <div class="well">

 <?php $exid = get_the_ID(); ?>
 <?php 
  $description = $newdata[$exid]['Description']; 
  $sets = $newdata[$exid]['Sets'];
  $reps = $newdata[$exid]['Reps'];
  $rest = $newdata[$exid]['Rest'];
  $load = $newdata[$exid]['Load'];
  $tempo = $newdata[$exid]['Tempo'];
 ?>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
 <?php

                $exerciseID = get_the_ID();
                $blogUrl = get_site_url();
                global $wpdb;
                $query = "
                SELECT * 
                FROM imagemap
                WHERE exercise = '".$exerciseID."'";

                $result = $wpdb->get_results($query); 

                foreach($result as $row)
                 {
                  echo '<div class="imageGridImages">';
                  // echo "<img src=".$blogUrl. "/image/thumb/".$row->id. ".jpg />";
                  echo '<div class="image display" style="background-image: url('  .$blogUrl.'/image/thumb/' .$row->id. '.jpg);"></div>';

                  echo '</div>';
                 }

                  // echo $row->id." ".$row->exercise." ".$row->source." <br>";

                // echo $query;
                // var_dump($result)

                ?>
```

The way this should work is to receive the saved data from the database unserialize the collection and then display the collection. I have got this working fine throughout the site however this seems to be baffling me.

I have been trying to use something like `$newdata = maybe_unserialize($result['collection_data']);` However this does not give me any joy.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get access to the serialised data within the array by using:

```
$result[0]->collection_data
```

Answer (score 0):

you can extract the data

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

```
$unserialize =  unserialize ($result[0]->collection_data); 
var_dump($unserialize);
```